# Unity 2D не получается задать движение машине

Tags: c#, unity3d

Машина не едет, два колеса привязанные к машине.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D frontWheel;
    public Rigidbody2D backWheel;
    public float speed;
    private float movement;
    void Start  () {

    }
      void Update () {
        movement = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        backWheel.AddTorque(movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        frontWheel.AddTorque(movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    } 
  }
```

Ошибка вылазит вот такая:
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable backWheel of CarPhysics has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the backWheel variable of the CarPhysics script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D.AddTorque (System.Single torque) (at :0)
CarPhysics.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/CarPhysics.cs:20)

Но я не понимаю почему Unity думает что заднее и переднее колесо не назначены, они же назначены в инспекторе...
А ещё: "movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime" и "Input.GetAxis" подсвечиваются как переменные

Comment: А как мы можем знать, указаны они в инспекторе или нет, если вы не приложили скриншот инспектора?.. Так movement, speed...это и есть переменные: вы их сами объявили :)

Comment: @МаксимФисман Ну переменные movement и speed да, я говорю про Time.fixedDeltaTime и Input.GetAxis. [Google](https://imgur.com/a/EzpuLCg)

Comment: А в чем проблема-то с переменными? GetAxis подсвечивается желтым, т.к. это метод, fixedDeltaTime - это [public static float fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) - как бы тоже переменная